# parsed array only returns last object

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am parsing an array into multiple smaller arrays but the returned result to my main is the last object in the original array. I understand why it is happening but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my main class calling my class parseUDP to parse the array:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MarketDataReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        byte[] i = null;
        //byte[] decodedArray = null;
        String readableMessage = "Null Null";
        ipaddrConnection ip = new ipaddrConnection();
        parseUDP p = new parseUDP();
        DecodeMessage message = new DecodeMessage();

        while(1==1){
            i = ip.getPacket();
            byte[] decodedArray = p.parseUDP(i);
            //decodedArray = p.

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : decodedArray) 
            {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
            }
            System.out.println("new: " + sb.toString());

            //readableMessage = message.decode(decodedArray);
            //System.out.println(readableMessage);

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MarketDataReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

}
```

Here is my class to parse the original Array into smaller arrays:

```
public class parseUDP {

public byte[] parseUDP(byte[] i) {
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(i);
    byte[] newArr = null;
    byte[] headerArr = new byte[12];
    byte[] head;
    byte[] completeArray= null;


    head = Arrays.copyOf(i, 12);
    buffer.get(headerArr);

    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {

        buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        buffer.mark();
        int length = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
        if (length == 0) {
            break;
        }
        //System.out.println(length);
        newArr = new byte[length];
        buffer.reset();
        buffer.get(newArr, 0, length);

        completeArray = new byte[head.length + newArr.length];
        for(int x = 0; x < head.length; x++)
        {
            completeArray[x] = head[x];  
        }

        for(int x = head.length, j = 0; j < newArr.length; x++, j++)
        {
            completeArray[x] = newArr[j];  
        }  

        return completeArray;
    }
    return completeArray;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you are facing this problem because you are calling the method `parseUDP` on an object under which u have same objects defined. It's getting complected unnecessarily. Make the method static and access call method as `ParseUDP.parseUDP(arr)`. `EDIT:` If you see my way, there is no special need for that class as it has only one method which is completely static so why not make it just a method?

Comment: I have to then break the smaller parsed arrays down even more. I thought a separate class would be cleaner by containing these two separate functions.